# Display values from several tables that share one foreign key

Tags: php, mysql

In mysql database I have 5 tables stored. I am using php for storing and retrieving data. I would like to retrieve/echo/display information of those 5 tables but in a linked manner. I have `academy_id` as the foreign key on each table.  Each academy has a contact person. Some academies may share the same contact person. But not sure how I can display each academy with its unique information. How can I can display these values through php/mysql select query?

```
Academy Name | MOU_ID | Academy_ID | STATUS | Academy Created | Course Name | Course Start Date | Instructor First Name | Contact First Name
```

Tables

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `academies` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `name` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `mou_id` int(11) default NULL,
  `academy_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `status` enum('INACTIVE','ACTIVE') NOT NULL default 'ACTIVE',
  `created_date` date NOT NULL
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
);

INSERT INTO `courses` (`course_id`, `course_name`) VALUES
(1, 'MATH'),
(2, 'ENGLISH'),
(3, 'BIOLOGY'),

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `academy_courses` (
  `unique_id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `academy_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `course_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `start_date` date default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`unique_id`),
  KEY `course_id` (`academy_id`,`course_id`)
);


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `instructors` (
  `instructor_id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `academy_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `instructor_fname` varchar(50) NOT NULL
  PRIMARY KEY  (`instructor_id`),
  KEY `academy_id` (`academy_id`)
);


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `main_contact` (
  `contact_id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `academy_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `contact_fname` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`contact_id`),
  KEY `academy_id` (`academy_id`)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `main_contact_bridge` (
  `academy_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `contact_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`contact_id`,`academy_id`),
  KEY `academy_id` (`academy_id`)
);
```

Comment: Is it every course you want to display?

Comment: You are missing the courses table no?

Comment: You want a join, and in this case a dedicated view is probably a good idea. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/views.html

Comment: @FilipeSilva I didnt include the `course` table because it only displayed a list of courses to choose from. The `academy_courses` stores the course chosen from `courses`

Comment: @Code_Ed_Student. Yes, but not the name of the course. And you probably should have some connection between instructor and course. otherwise, these queries will give you lots of duplicate results. And also explain what is the connection of the contact tables to the rest

Comment: @FilipeSilva Alright, true. How would you suggest I do the query?

Comment: @Code_Ed_Student. I'll try and explain what i would do. In the meantime, don't forget to explain what are the contact tables.

Comment: @FilipeSilva Alright, Added a description of what the contact tables are. Each academy has a contact person and some academies may share the same contact person.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would add the instructor_id to the academy_courses, otherwise if you have multiple instructors, you will get all the data duplicated for each instructor. Then you would do:

```sql
SELECT a.name AS 'Academy Name', 
       a.mou_id AS 
       a.academy_id
       a.status
       a.created_date AS 'Academy Created',
       c.course_name AS 'Course Name',
       ac.start_date AS 'Course Start Date',
       i.instructor_fname AS 'Instructor First Name',
       co.contact_fname AS 'Contact First Name'
FROM academies a
INNER JOIN academy_courses ac ON a.id = ac.academy_id
INNER JOIN courses c ON c.id = ac.course_id
INNER JOIN instructors i ON i.instructor_id = ac.instructor_id
INNER JOIN main_contact co ON co.academy_id = a.id
```

If you want to get information from Academy even if courses/academy_courses/etc don't exist, you can write a LEFT JOIN instead.

Comment: Did you mean `From academies a`?

Comment: Its OK :). But what is `AS` purpose? Also not sure how to add the `nstructor_id` to academy_courses, since information would be first submitted and then right away displayed/echoed. The `instructor_id` at that moment would not exists until after data is submitted.

Comment: The AS is to say that that column will have an alias(the text that follows).
About the isntructor_id, you should create the academy, then the course, then the instructor, only then the academy_course with the id's that you want to have for that record.

Comment: And you should also add foreign keys to your tables. academy_id, instructor_id, course_id in tables other than the original should be foreign keys.

Comment: Oh, but in the form I am doing everything at once. I request for academy, course and a instructor info all at once and then store the results in db once form is submitted. I have to do each one in that order you mentioned? different forms?

Comment: Yes. If you are creating them all from the same form, you would do it in that order and use the ID's to create the academy_course. But maybe you should have different forms to create an academy, then other to create an isntructor, a course. And then to create the academy_course you could give those values as a dropdownlist for the user to select and create the record.(Just a suggestion)

Comment: Alright, this seems like a complex process but it is the right way.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you're trying to get:

```
SELECT a.name, a.mou_id, a.academy_id, a.status, a.created_date, ac.course_id, ac.start_date, i.instructor_fname, mc.contact_fname
FROM academy_courses ac 
LEFT JOIN academies a USING (academy_id) 
LEFT JOIN instructors i USING (academy_id) 
LEFT JOIN main_contact mc USING (academy_id);
```

Comment: How come `FROM academy_courses ac` and not `FROM academies a` and then `LEFT JOIN academy_courses a USING (academy_id) `?

Comment: You're getting a list of courses, that's why. Not a list of academies. You're getting the courses with the associated information for that course. It made more sense in my head that way.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking is to Join the tables. There are different types of joins. Please take a look at this explanation http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html