# Inserting values based on results of another insert

Tags: mysql

There are two tables in mysql database `academy` and `instructors`. I want to insert values to each table in the following order(pseudo code):

- 1st INSERT INTO  `academy` values `acad_name, address, street, city,
  state`
- 2nd INSERT INTO `instructors` values `instructor_name`
- 3rd
  INSERT INTO  `academy` values `instructor_id` FROM `instructors`
  \this records should go with the corresponding `academy_id`

The third insert is based on the results of the second insert `instructor_id` which is auto_increment. But I want the third insert to correspond to the current academy the values where inserted to previously how can I do so?

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `academy` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `academy_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `instructor_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `street_address` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `city` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `state` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `instructor_id` (`instructor_id`) // Foreign KEY
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `instructors` (
  `instructor_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `academy_id` int(11) NOT NULL
  PRIMARY KEY (`instructor_id`),
  KEY `academy_id` (`academy_id`) // Foreign KEY
);
```

Comment: 3rd one is actually updating the entry inserted in 1st ??

Comment: your table design is having circular FK! academy_id Foreign KEY in instructors and instructor_id is Foreign KEY in academy table.

Comment: @Damodaran reason is for another question asked previously, [Stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19959164/display-values-from-several-tables-that-share-one-foreign-key/19960089?noredirect=1#comment29710299_19960089)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your table structure is a little confusing. Why have an auto incrementing 'id' field in table academy when you have an 'academy_id' field that would (I assume) be unique, use 'academy_id' as the primary key.

The table structure implies a many-to-many relationship with each table having a foreign key constraint for the other table, assuming under normal circumstances that an instructor belongs to only one academy but an academy can have many instructors you should remove the foreign key constraint from table academy and then just reference all the instructors belonging to that academy from the foreign key constraint in table instructors.

If the scenario implies that there must be a many-to-many relationship then you must create an intersection entity. Meaning that if a academy has many instructors and an instructor can have many academies then you create a new table with two foreign key constraints from table academy and instructor with a unique id field as well for the new table.

Answer (score 1):

You can use insert id function to retrive the id of the academy table and add into the other table insertion.

**mysqli**

```
mysqli_insert_id();
```

**mysql**

```
 mysql_insert_id();
```

Answer (score 0):

First insert the entry in academy table and then in to instructors table. Then use

> [mysql_insert_id](https://www.php.net/mysql_insert_id)

get the last inserted id and update the entry in academy table.
[Check this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1685860/php-how-to-get-last-inserted-id-of-a-table)

Answer (score 0):

You can query the value of the auto increment column after each insert,
e.g.

```
SELECT @insert_id:=`AUTO_INCREMENT`
FROM  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'YourDatabaseName'
AND   TABLE_NAME   = 'YourTableName';
)
```

or

```
INSERT INTO `academy`(`id`) VALUES (NULL);
SET @last_insert_id = LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

set that to a user defined variable and then use it on the consecutive inserts.

However if multiple - parallel inserts take place you must also use lock tables in order to use correct autoincrement id values.

`http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/lock-tables.html`